# Larvel 9 pagination with limit

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-query-builder

Working inside a Laravel 9 project and need to limit my returned results and then paginate, I have over 40,000 total rows and would like to show no more than 500 entries as a paginated list.

When I add `limit` to my query it's still returning all my rows and isn't limiting, what am I missing?

```php
$query = Application::query();
$query = $query->with(['payday', 'response', 'apiLinks']);

if ($request->input('filters.from')) {
    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->input('filters.from')));
}

if ($request->input('filters.to')) {
    $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($request->input('filters.to')));
}

if ($request->input('search')) {
    foreach ($request->input('search') as $field => $value) {
        $query->where($this->mapSearchField($field), $value);
    }
}

$query = $query->limit(500);
$query = $query->paginate(25);

return response()->json([
    'applications' => $query ?? []
], 200);
```

Comment: why use `limit(500)` if you `paginate(25)` which is equivalent to `limit(25)->get()` ? if you want to paginate with 500 element on each page, use `paginate(500)`

Comment: Because `paginate(25)` means to only show 25 results per page, this isn't a task of limiting results per page, this is a task of limiting the overall number of returned query results prior to pagination, in reality, I have millions of rows so it's not feasible to paginate all these. I ended up using `LengthAwarePaginator`

Comment: do you want to show 25 per page and only have a maximum of 20 pages or do you want to show 500 per page no matter how many pages are available. when you use `paginate(25)` it doesn't get all the records then only shows 25; the query only returns 25.

Comment: With a million of rows it looks silly having my pagination show thousands of potential pages. I want 500 records max, 25 per page = however many pages the paginator generates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in solution to limit the maximum number of pages with a LengthAwarePaginator

You will need to instantiate it yourself.

```
$query = Application::query();
$query = $query->with(['payday', 'response', 'apiLinks']);

if ($request->input('filters.from')) {
    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->input('filters.from')));
}

if ($request->input('filters.to')) {
    $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($request->input('filters.to')));
}

if ($request->input('search')) {
    foreach ($request->input('search') as $field => $value) {
        $query->where($this->mapSearchField($field), $value);
    }
}
//current page
$page = \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page');

//total number of element (we force max to 500)
$total = min($query->count(), 500);

//the items for current page (25 is items per page)
$items = $query->forPage($page, 25)->get();

//we instantiate the paginator manually (25 is items per page)
$results = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items, $total, 25, $page);

return response()->json([
    'applications' => $results
], 200);
```

Yeah, no out of the box answer for this one.